# get nearby from mysql database with latitude and longitude

Tags: php, codeigniter, maps

I have event database that has multiple events, each event has different latitude and longitude, if  my current latitude is 30.7263962 and longitude is 76.7664144, how I can fetch events from the database those are under 100 km range from my location? Can anyone suggest me query? Thanks

Comment: You need haversine formula

Comment: For performance reasons you can first make an inaccurate query with delta latitude and delta longitude, and afterwards check the found events with the haversine formula. Have a look at this [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19762) in gis.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Some example code you could bend to you will (I have tried to adapt for your needs, but have made some wild guesses).
This is a version of a the haversine algorithm, using Rhumb lines(or loxodrome)

```
<?php
function search($device_latitude, $device_longitude, $radius, $radius_type)
{
    $events = array();

    $sql = "SELECT `event_id`, `last_updated`, `location_lat`, `location_long` FROM `event`";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $geo_data = $this->_bearing_distance_calc($device_latitude, $device_longitude, $row->location_lat, $row->location_long, $radius_type);
            $geo_data['radius_type'] = $radius_type;
            // $geo_data contains => 'distance', 'bearing'
            if($geo_data['distance'] <= $radius)
            {
                $events[] = $this->event->load($row->event_id);
            }
        }
        return $events;
    }
    $this->error_msg = "Search failed.";
    return NULL;
}

function _bearing_distance_calc($device_latitude, $device_longitude, $event_latitude, $event_longitude, $radius_type)
{
    // using Rhumb lines(or loxodrome)
    // convert to rads for php trig functions
    $device_latitude = deg2rad($device_latitude);
    $device_longitude = deg2rad($device_longitude);
    $event_latitude = deg2rad($event_latitude);
    $event_longitude = deg2rad($event_longitude);

    // calculate delta of lat and long
    $delta_latitude = $event_latitude-$device_latitude;
    $delta_longitude = $event_longitude-$device_longitude;

    // earth radius
    if ($radius_type == 'Miles')
    {
        $earth_radius = 3959;
    }
    else
    {
        $earth_radius = 6371;
    }

    // now lets start mathing !!
    $dPhi = log(tan($event_latitude/2+M_PI/4)/tan($device_latitude/2+M_PI/4));
    if ($dPhi != 0)
    {
        $q = $delta_latitude/$dPhi;
    }
    else
    {
        $q = cos($device_latitude);
    }
    //$q = (!is_nan($delta_latitude/$dPhi)) ? $delta_latitude/$dPhi : cos($device_latitude);  // E-W line gives dPhi=0

    // if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb across 180° meridian:
    if (abs($delta_longitude) > M_PI)
    {
        $delta_longitude = $delta_longitude>0 ? -(2*M_PI-$delta_longitude) : (2*M_PI+$delta_longitude);
    }

    $geo_data = array();
    $geo_data['distance'] = sqrt($delta_latitude*$delta_latitude + $q*$q*$delta_longitude*$delta_longitude) * $earth_radius;
    $bearing = rad2deg(atan2($delta_longitude, $dPhi));

    if($bearing < 0)
    {
        $bearing = 360 + $bearing;
    }
    $geo_data['bearing'] = $bearing;

    return $geo_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to translate the distance into degrees of longitude and latitude, filter based on those to bound the entries that are roughly in the bounding box, then do a more precise distance filter. Here is great paper that explains how to do all this:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL